# How to fix CMakeList for project build with SDL_image?

Tags: cmake, sdl-2, clion

I try to build project with SDL2_image, but have such error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
By not providing "FindSDL2_image.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"SDL2_image", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SDL2_image" with
any of the following names:

SDL2_imageConfig.cmake
sdl2_image-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "SDL2_image" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"SDL2_image_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If
"SDL2_image" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.
```

If compile project with CTRL+F5, it works fine.

I work with ubuntu 20.04, Clion, also add `FindSDL2_image.cmake` to cmake/Modules. Can someone help with it?

My CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(POng2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)


include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(POng2 main.cpp Game.h Game.cpp Paddle.h Paddle.cpp Entity.h Entity.cpp Ball.h 
               Ball.cpp Board.h Board.cpp Score.h Score.cpp)

target_link_libraries(POng2 ${SDL2_LIBRARY}
        ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES}
        ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: It you put the script into `/Modules`, then you need to add that directory to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. But you current script adds `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake`.

Comment: I edit my CMakeList by: set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/203.7717.62/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.17/Modules"). But it didn`t help. Did I make something wrong?

Comment: `/.local` doesn't  look like a correct path: the directory `.local` (with dot!) unlikely exists in the root directory. Probably, you have this directory under the **home** directory (`~/.local`). In the case the path should start with `$ENV{HOME}/.local`.

Comment: BTW, modifying `cmake-xx/Modules` directory is a bad practice: CMake installation should not be modified. You may ship the module `FindSDL2_image.cmake` with your project, by placing it under `cmake/` directory in the project.